Unity UI: Brick Pattern Grid (Running bond)
I'm trying to make a grid, but one with an offset/staggering on every other row.
Ideally, it will be populated with >20 (up to a theoretically infinite amount ideally, but probably nothing higher than 30/40), but for the time being, it will be of a much lower count, and thus it will need to work no matter how many "bricks" I have.

The "bricks" themselves are 2:1 clickable UI images on a canvas in a mask within a scrollable rect. Ideally they would have some padding between the images, but it's not a disaster. They are not allowed to be inline with a brick beneath or above, a sort-of example is shown beneath 6.
There is one other thing I would like this grid to be able to do, just a note: when you hover over one of the clickable images, it will expand (increase scale proportionally), and gain a shadow. I know how to do the shadow and the increase in scale, but it is a consideration for this potentially custom grid solution.
There may be a really simple solution, but I haven't found anything useful yet! When I search for anything similar to this, the only formula I get is for how many bricks I need in an area of a wall, which is not what I'm looking for.

For the implementation of each row, I was planning on using an otherwise empty rect with a horizontal layout, and repeat this for each row, probably sticking the rows in a vertical group.
But the problem, I have is, how do I calculate in C# (at runtime), how many "bricks" are to go in each row (and how many rows are needed)? It should make use of vertical space (size of the parent may vary), as well as horizontal, so a simple alternating pattern along two/three rows won't work for larger numbers, >7.
I'm a bit stuck, but any help would be appreciated.

So before implementing anything in code first make up in your mind: what is the rules these setup has to follow? How do YOU know how the pattern should look like? And how can you then go ahead and generalize it into an algorithm that works for any number of blocks ... this is so far nothing to do with Unity nor c# and I would claim is off topic for StackOverflow. Here we ask specific coding related questions once we already have a specific attempt of implementation

For instance how should 11 look like? Worst case just hard code the 30-40 patterns manually .. that's not too many and in order to get things started, why not ;) you will by then probably anyway see yourself the similarities in the patterns and maybe understand better how you could automate it for any amount

Also ... why not 4 - 3 - 2 - 1 for the 10? Or the other way round if your attempt was also minimal height then why not 4 - 3 - 2 for the 9 .. similar to how you did 6? .. 7 could also be 4 - 3 (which considering actual physical bricks would make more sense) .. etc .. what I mean is: Whether you use UI and which components exactly to implement this is quite secondary ... first you have to figure out how to construct your rows at all

You can makes some "rules" by which you can infer the validity of your construction. Track the last placement; evaluate the situation, and reject the block if it is "bad". e.g. even number row above / below any odd number row. The "base" row always has the most blocks (and 1 more that any above or below, etc). Using a "HorizontalAlignment" of "Center" (and Vertical as desired), you get the automatic centering; where each row is a horizontal StackPanel, or (single row) VariableWrapGrip or (single row) UniformGrid (and so forth). And of course the "item size" (or cell size) should be the same. (The rows can be stacked vertically in a vertical StackPanel ... that is centered or whatever in the Window). All this can be done without actually updating the UI until necessary.
